# Select all checked checkboxes with similar id's using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, checkbox

This might be the easiest question of the day.

i have a groups of checkboxes with similar id's (all starting with `someid_` like `someid_0`,`someid_1`..)

i want to get all `checked` checkboxes.

I have tried `$('input:checkbox[id^="someid_"]:checked')` but it's not working?

Comment: your code seems correct. what version of jQuery are you using? can you post a full example somewhere online?

Comment: check the demo code is correct check for jquery versions also!

Comment: I think the problem is something else..

Answer (score 40, accepted):

this code is working check demo

http://jsfiddle.net/csTpG/

Markup

```
<input type="checkbox" id="someid_1" checked/>
<input type="checkbox" id="someid_2" checked/>
<input type="checkbox" id="someid_3" checked/>
<input type="checkbox" id="someid_4"/>
```

jQuery

```
var n = $('input:checkbox[id^="someid_"]:checked').length;
alert(n); // count of checked checkboxes

$('input:checkbox[id^="someid_"]:checked').each(function(){
    alert($(this).attr("id"));});
```

Comment: i think he want to slect all checkboxes which have similar id not to find checked checkbox id

Answer (score 1):

the code you tried is absolutely correct, may b the code ran before parsing the required elements so try,

```
$(document).ready(function(){$('input:checkbox[id^="someid_"]:checked')})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var isChecked = false;

        function allSelected() 
        {
            // this line is for toggle the check
            isChecked = !isChecked;

            //below line refers to 'jpCheckbox' class
            $('input:checkbox.jpCheckbox').attr('checked',isChecked);

            //OR,
            //$('input:checkbox.jpCheckbox').attr('checked','checked');
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        Select All<input type="checkbox" id="selectAllCheckbox" onclick="allSelected()" /><br/>

        A<input type="checkbox" id="jpCheckbox" class="jpCheckbox" /><br/>
        B<input type="checkbox" id="jpCheckbox" class="jpCheckbox" /><br/>
        C<input type="checkbox" id="jpCheckbox" class="jpCheckbox" /><br/>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi, try this approach, this one is working for select / deselect all multiple checkboxes with same class on same form.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can do a search on the ID attribute. it usually returns only one value. You can set the class to some_0 instead and then search or use a custom attribute like

```
<input type=checkbox customattr=some_1>
```

Answer (score -1):

try  this...

```
$('input:checkbox').filter('#someid').attr(":checked")
```

Comment: Why would you select all checkboxes and then filter out by ID? This code is also not retrieving the checked boxes, it's retrieving the ":checked" attribute from `#someid`. You meant to write `$('#someid)`